# VueJS Watcher not initializing correctly on Safari 12+

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, safari, race-condition

I run into a Problem with vueJS at version 2.6.11 and Safari version 12 and 13.

On some pages of the webapp the vue watchers are not initalizing correctly, appearently because of a race-condition inside the vue initalization.
The error results in, that on some pages of the Webapp, none of the v-if bindings and stuff like this works anymore.

Currently on version 2.6.11 i even do not get an error. Luckily on an older version (don't remember exactly which one it was), i got an console error which leaded me to:

```
this.getter.call(vm, vm);
```

in `vue/src/core/observer/watcher.js:106`
with the error `string does not match the expected pattern`

setting breakpoints to this part of the code, when the exception appeared, and running `this.getter.call(vm, vm);` again using the browser console, results in a working page after the rendering is finished. So it seems to be because of a race-condition i guess ?

This part of the code is called multiple times during the app initalization.
`this.getter` is using the function `function (){e._update(e._render(),n)}` (minified), when the error appears.

Anyone encountered the same issue, and/or knows a fix for this problem ?